# Cómo agregar texto desde un select a un textarea donde se encuentra el cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Hola quiero agregar texto desde un select a un textarea en la parte donde quedo el cursor, pero solo logro que se inserte al comienzo del textarea y no donde esta el cursor

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').focus(function(){
   var campo=$('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').val();
   $('#longMensaje').text(campo.length);
  }); 
  $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').keydown(function(){
   var campo=$('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').val();
   $('#longMensaje').text(campo.length);
  });
  $( '#txtAreaPreviewMensaje' ).keyup(function() {
     var campo=$('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').val();
   $('#longMensaje').text(campo.length);
  });
  $('#selecccionar').change(function(){
   var value=$('#selecccionar').val();
   if(value===''||value===null){

   }else{
    var pos = $("#ultimaPosicion").val(); 
    var textoActual = $("#txtAreaPreviewMensaje").val();
    var textoInsertar = value;
    var position = pos;
    var output = [textoActual.slice(0, position), textoInsertar, textoActual.slice(position)].join('');
    $("#txtAreaPreviewMensaje").val(output);
    $("#txtAreaPreviewMensaje").focus();
   }
  });  
  /*function posicion(pos){
   $('ultimaPosicion').val(pos);
  }*/
  $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').blur(function(){
   var end = $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').prop('selectionEnd');
   $('ultimaPosicion').val(end);
  });
  });
```

```html
<html> 
<head> 
 <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head> 
<body>  
 <select id="selecccionar">
  <option value="">selecionar dato...</option>
  <option value="Emmanuel">Emmanuel</option>
  <option value="Cristina">Cristina</option>
  <option value="Alicia">Alicia</option>
  <option value="Esjani">Esjani</option>
 </select>
 <br> 
 <br>   
 <textarea  id="txtAreaPreviewMensaje" name="mensaje" wrap=physical cols="28" rows="4" ></textarea> 
 <p id="longMensaje"><p>  
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="hidden" id="ultimaPosicion" value="0"> 
</body> 
</htm>
```

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo (sin necesidad de jQuery) de como insertar texto en la posición del cursor

```js
var campo = document.getElementById('campo');
var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
var insertar = 'hola';

boton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  var inicio = campo.selectionStart;
  var fin = campo.selectionEnd;
  var texto = campo.value;
  campo.value = texto.slice(0, inicio) + insertar + texto.slice(fin);
  campo.selectionStart = campo.selectionEnd = inicio + insertar.length;
  campo.focus();
});
```

```html
<textarea id="campo">0123456789</textarea>
<button id="boton">Insertar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día colega! Creo que ese código esta un poco desorganizado, pero atendiendo a tu consulta te dejo esta solución. Fíjate en la parte del output... Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para resolver el asunto. Espero te resulte útil!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').focus(function () {
        var campo = $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').val();
        $('#longMensaje').text(campo.length);
    });
    $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').keydown(function () {
        var campo = $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').val();
        $('#longMensaje').text(campo.length);
    });
    $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').keyup(function () {
        var campo = $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').val();
        $('#longMensaje').text(campo.length);
    });
    $('#selecccionar').change(function () {
        var value = $('#selecccionar').val();
        if (value === '' || value === null) {
            return;
        } else {
            var pos = $("#ultimaPosicion").val();
            var textoActual = $("#txtAreaPreviewMensaje").val();
            var textoInsertar = value;
            var output = `${textoActual} ${textoInsertar}`;
            $("#txtAreaPreviewMensaje").val(output);
            $("#txtAreaPreviewMensaje").focus();
        }
    });
    /*function posicion(pos){
        $('ultimaPosicion').val(pos);
    }*/
    $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').blur(function () {
        var end = $('#txtAreaPreviewMensaje').prop('selectionEnd');
        $('ultimaPosicion').val(end);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <select id="selecccionar">
    <option value="">selecionar dato...</option>
    <option value="Emmanuel">Emmanuel</option>
    <option value="Cristina">Cristina</option>
    <option value="Alicia">Alicia</option>
    <option value="Esjani">Esjani</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="txtAreaPreviewMensaje" name="mensaje" wrap=physical cols="28" rows="4"></textarea>
    <p id="longMensaje">
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="ultimaPosicion" value="0">

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```